# get EnvironmentObject property within method

Tags: swiftui, environmentobject

I need to access an EnvironmentObject from a method within a View-Extension, so I cannot add an @EnvironmentObject property.

I tried to do it like

```
extension View {
    func myFunc() {
        let something = EnvironmentObject<MyType>()
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work - is there another/better way to get it from within the method?

Comment: This way it is definitely impossible - just opposite to EnvironmentObject concept. Would you give more context, so we could try to find different way?

Comment: I don't understand _why_ I can't declare an \@EnvironmentObject property in a View extension—I know you can't ordinarily declare properties in extensions because you can't allocate storage in an extension, but does \@EnvironmentObject really allocate storage under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the object as a parameter:

```
extension View {
    func myFunc(myType: MyType) -> some View {
        // do something with `myType`
    }
}
```